# CSS "right" attribute not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, user-interface, chat

I'm coding a UI for a chat application. I have a list of messages, which are styled on a different way depending on if the sender is the own user or another user.

The problem is that when I set the `right` attribute for a message (which has its `position` attribute set to `relative`) the element seems to be taking the same reference point as `left`. And the more pixels I add to the value the farther the element moves to the left, but starting from the left side of the own element.

The actual result is this:

[image]

And what I want is the "a" messages to be aligned to the right.

The css code for the speech bubbles is the following:

```
    .speech {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding:5px;
  margin: 1px 3px;
  border:2px solid #5a8f00;
  color:#333;
  background-color: #df9;
  /* css3 */
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.speech::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#5a8f00 transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}
.speech.otherown::before {
  top:10px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left:-27.5px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:3px 10px 3px 15px;
  border-color:transparent #5a8f00;
}
.speech.userown::before {
  top:10px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left: auto;
  right: -24.4px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:3px 10px 3px 12px;
  border-color:transparent #5a8f00;
}
.speech.userown {
  margin-right: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
.speech.otherown {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

And the HTML is the following:

```
<section class="conversation">
<div class="messages">
  <ul>
    <li class="speech userown">Message a</li><br>
    <li class="speech otherown">Message b</li><br>
    <li class="speech userown">Message a</li><br>
    <li class="speech userown">Message a</li><br>
    <li class="speech otherown">Message b</li><br>
    <li class="speech userown">Message a</li><br>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="sendmsg" class="sendmsg"></div>
</section>
```

The whole code is at http://github.com/dieortin/crowdspeak .

Comment: Please put the code to change here. And be more specific with what you want by giving an example of the desired output or live demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element with `position:relative` has `right` styling, think of it as representing "how many pixels away from this element's original right position it should be". The same goes for `left`, `top`, and `bottom`--the reference point is the original position of the element. So adding pixels to `right` pushes it left, and adding pixels to `left` pushes it right.

If you want it to be X pixels from the right side of its container, try using `position:absolute` instead.

**Edit**: In this specific case, it might be better to use `float` instead of absolute positioning. Try adding the following:

```
.speech {
  clear:both;
}
.speech.userown {
  float:right;
}
.speech.otherown {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Using absolute positioning how can I prevent consecutive elements from overlapping?

Comment: After looking at your edit and seeing exactly what you want to do, I'd probably choose to use `float:left` / `float:right` and `clear:both` rather than `position:absolute` and `left:0` / `right:0`. There's no easy way to solve the overlapping problem with absolutely positioned elements; you'd probably need to detect their heights with JavaScript. Floated elements, however, "take up space" on the page, so you could easily add messages below one another.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much! This completely solved my problem, I had tried using float but the messages always overlapped - I didn't even know the `clear` property existed

Answer (score 2):

The position needs to be set to `absolute` or `fixed` to obey the `right` property.